# duplicate ajax calls when include jquery ujs in rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

i am developing a basic depot application with rails 
i have added a button

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) , remote: true %>
```

when i click on home page hyperlink then click on the button again , ajax gets duplicated , if i click on home page 3 times , the button ajax call 3 times and so on

Note : the problem disappear when i remove jquery-ujs from application.js

line_item controller

```
def create
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product product
@line_item.save
respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to store_url }
    format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

home page action

```
def index
@products = Product.order(:title)
@cart = current_cart
end
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js,
// listed below.
//
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

ajax response should render this js file
show.js.erb

```
$('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");
//#START_HIGHLIGHT
$('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88ff88'})
.animate({'background-color':'#114411'} , 1000);
```

using gem jquery rails 4.0.4

Comment: Please include your jQuery and your .js.erb view file in your post.

Comment: i added them , thanks for notice

Comment: I don't see your AJAX view file in the post @Mohamed.  Also, typically, your `create` action would result in a page reload and you would use a separate action name for your AJAX action.

Comment: the ajax is added when i added the attribute remote='true' , the response is the line , format.js . it should render create.js then send it as the response
the problem that clicking the button 'add to cart' send duplicate ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the problem . using turbolink with javascript link tags outside head load an extra jquery script every time i click on home page , a dummy  solution is to put javascript link tag inside the head itself

Comment: This is usually always a problem with duplicate jquery inclusion. Remember to mark your own answer as the answer, so the question is listed as solved :)